# How to supress page header on report footer in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 4 page header section and all my terms and conditions appear on my page 3 onwards. 3-6 pages for terms and conditions which are in page footer. I need to suppress the header on my page footer.FYI, I had the issue of last section of the page duplicating on my nextpage.henceforth conditionally suppressed all my text object in the page header section. I'm unable to use pagecount on the section -> sectionexpert -> formula due to this duplication.

Comment: Why can't you just use the section suppression formula `PageNumber>=3`?

Comment: I did try that on my page header but unfortunately the last section of the page gets duplicated on the next page.